# Nodejs unit test email notifications on failure

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, notifications

I am using mocha, chain, nyc supertest for unit test in my nodejs app. I am able to generate test reports at the end of the run, but is there anyway to send email notifications when a test fails during a test run or email a test report?

Comment: What testing framework are you using?

Comment: Updated post with info.

Comment: @sotn you can use [`after`](https://mochajs.org/#hooks) hook with [`nodemailer`](https://nodemailer.com/about/) to send report in mail after all the test blocks are completed

Comment: @sotn Is this needed when these unit tests run during PR checks in git/bitbucket like in travis or git actions? Because Node libraries require the password to send the mail, which you possibly might need to store in code/db, which might be risky.

If you need it locally itself, such libs can help

Answer (score 0):

@sotn, You can write the mail notification function call inside of after hook,
to send the mail with html attachment you can refer to below answer.

[Send email with html attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55357774/how-do-i-send-a-html-file-using-nodemailer)